# change the background video of the website according to the weather

Tags: javascript, html, css

There was a problem with the above. I want a dynamic video background for a website. It would change exactly what the weather is like outside, so if it rains, it will play a rainy video in the background, if the sun is shining it will be a sunny video and so on.
I already have a basic snippet of code that works, but I can only use images, not video.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>Dinamic Weather Background</title>
          <style>
          body[category="Clear"]
            {
              background-image: url('images/ClearSky.png');
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: 1920px 1080px;
              background-color: lightblue;                 
            }

          body[category="Clouds"]
            {
              background-image: url('images/CloudSky.png');
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: 1920px 1080px;
              background-color: silver;
            }

          body[category="Rain"]
            {
              background-image: url('images/RainSky.png');
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: 1920px 1080px;
              background-color: dimgray;
            }

          body[category="Thunderstorm"]
            {
              background-image: url('images/ThunderstormSky.png');
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: 1920px 1080px;
              background-color: lightblue;                 
            }

          body[category="Drizzle"]
            {
              background-image: url('images/DrizzleSky.png');
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: 1920px 1080px;
              background-color: lightblue;                 
            }

          body[category="Snow"]
            {
              background-image: url('images/SnowSky.png');
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: 1920px 1080px;
              background-color: lightblue;                 
            }

          body[category="Clear"] .category
            {
              color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            }
          body[category="Clouds"] .category
            {
              color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            }
          body[category="Rain"] .category
            {
              color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            }
          body[category="Thunderstorm"] .category
            {
              color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            }
          body[category="Drizzle"] .category
            {
              color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            }
          body[category="Snow"] .category
            {
              color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            }
          .name1
          {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
          }
          .desc
          {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
          }
          .temp
          {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
          }
          </style>
</head>
<body>
            <div>
              <div class="name1"></div>
              <div class="desc"></div>
              <div class="temp"></div>
              <div class="category">
            </div>
            
            <script language="JavaScript">
                var button = document.querySelector('.button')
                var name1 = document.querySelector('.name1');
                var desc = document.querySelector('.desc');
                var temp = document.querySelector('.temp'); 
                var category = document.querySelector('.category'); 


                fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=T%C3%B6r%C3%B6kszentmikl%C3%B3s&appid=fa7e76863d7bd04e06e348ab8e1973de')
                .then(response => response.json()) 
                .then(data => {
                      var nameValue = data['name'];
                      var categoryValue =data['weather'][0]['main'];
                      var tempValue = data['main']['temp'];
                      var descValue = data['weather'][0]['description'];
                      var tofloat = Math.abs(tempValue - 273.15);
                      var tempCelcius= parseFloat(tofloat).toFixed(2);

                          name1.innerHTML = nameValue;
                          category.innerHTML = categoryValue;
                          temp.innerHTML = tempCelcius;
                          desc.innerHTML = descValue;

                document.body.setAttribute("category", categoryValue);
                              })
                .catch(err => alert("Wrong City Name!"))
                                                        
            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone have any idea how I could solve this? Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like that ? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp

Comment: No, i want a dynamic background video that changes depending on the weather. as in the example above the background changes in my code, although i want to achieve this not only with pictures but with video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar but it's an image instead of video

```html
<img src="" id="img1" height="200" width="200">
<script>
var nameValue;
var categoryValue;
var tempValue;
var descValue;
var tofloat;
var tempCelcius;

let image=document.getElementById("img1");
fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=T%C3%B6r%C3%B6kszentmikl%C3%B3s&appid=fa7e76863d7bd04e06e348ab8e1973de')
.then(response => response.json()) 
.then(data => {
nameValue = data['name'];
categoryValue = data['weather'][0]['main'];
tempValue = data['main']['temp'];
descValue = data['weather'][0]['description'];
tofloat = Math.abs(tempValue - 273.15);
tempCelcius= parseFloat(tofloat).toFixed(2);

document.body.setAttribute("category", categoryValue);
}).then(setsrcByWeather);


function setsrcByWeather() {
switch (categoryValue.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
case "clouds" || "cloud":
image.src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQVm3SUs1jcFOCDZRkSa4wuMW-pcEfx3EIpQF1zNzVPmaMPFiS-Eiim3RYvuEwh8_G-PlY&usqp=CAU";
break;
case "sunny" || "sun":
image.src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
break;
case "rain" || "rainy":
image.src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
break;
}}


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks man! Your code was useful to me. I changed the <img> extension to <video> and it works!

Answer (score 0):

A working code if someone could run something similar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <video autoplay muted loop id="vid1">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
<script>
var nameValue;
var categoryValue;
var tempValue;
var descValue;
var tofloat;
var tempCelcius;

let source=document.getElementById("vid1");
fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=T%C3%B6r%C3%B6kszentmikl%C3%B3s&appid=fa7e76863d7bd04e06e348ab8e1973de')
.then(response => response.json()) 
.then(data => {
nameValue = data['name'];
categoryValue = data['weather'][0]['main'];
tempValue = data['main']['temp'];
descValue = data['weather'][0]['description'];
tofloat = Math.abs(tempValue - 273.15);
tempCelcius= parseFloat(tofloat).toFixed(2);

document.body.setAttribute("category", categoryValue);
}).then(setsrcByWeather);


function setsrcByWeather() {
switch (categoryValue.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
case "clouds" || "clouds":
source.src="images/Clouds.mp4";
break;
case "clear" || "clear":
source.src="images/Clear.mp4";
break;
case "rain" || "rain":
source.src="images/Rain.mp4";
break;
}}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm glad that the code worked for you, but change, this `"clouds" || "clouds"` as there is no meaning to check for `same OR same`, instead type like I typed in the answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).